# Google Sheets checkboxes not rendered correctly on mobile

Tags: google-sheets, mobile

I am using columns of checkboxes on some Google sheets that I have shared for read-only access. On a mobile device, the users see TRUE or FALSE in the columns instead of the boxes. On a PC it looks correct in the browser. So far it doesn't seem to matter which mobile browser they are using; it shows wrong on the browser built into the Facebook app, the browser built into the Google app, Safari and Chrome.

The solution is for them to install the Google Sheets app for Android or iOS, but I would rather not have that as a requirement. Sheets without checkboxes look correct in the mobile browsers. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't any workaround other than having Google Sheets app which was made for such purposes.

The other option is to have your viewers to switch on "desktop view" on their devices at the browser level:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the "last resort", you can modify your sheet's checkboxes and use something fake like:

```
=IF(A1=1;   
    IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/DgTwvYi.png");
    IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/8AxCgKZ.png"))
```

or

```
=IF(A1=1; "☑"; "☒")
```

## ☐ ☑ ☒ ☓ ✓ ✔ ✕ ✖ ✗ ✘

other custom shapes:

## ■ □ ▢ ▣ ▤ ▥ ▦ ▧ ▨ ▩ ▪ ▫ ▲ △ ▴ ▵ ▶ ▷ ▸ ▹ ▼ ▽ ▾ ▿ ◀ ◁ ◂ ◃ ◆ ◇ ◈ ◉ ○ ◌ ◍ ◎ ● ◐ ◑ ◒ ◓ ◩ ◪ ❍ ❏ ❐ ❑ ❒ ★ ☆ ✯ ✰ ✩ ✪ ✫ ✬ ✭ ✮ ✦ ✧♠ ♤ ♡ ♥ ♢ ♦ ♣ ♧ ✿ ❀ ♜ ♖ ♞ ♘ ♟ ♙ ♝ ♗ ♛ ♕ ♚ ♔ ⊗ ⊕